# How to use parameter substitution in glob pattern (zsh)

Tags: zsh, glob

I want to process a bunch of files ending in some suffixes, so I wrote the following zsh script but it did not work.

```
EXT=(.jpg .png .gif)
EXT=${(j.|.)EXT}    # EXT becomes '.jpg|.png|.gif'
for f in *($EXT); do     # should become '*(.jpg|.png|.gif)' but failed
    process-one-file $f
done
```

Why doesn't it work? How can I mix parameter substitution and glob pattern?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It does not work because in `zsh`, globbing is not done by default upon variable expansion. That why in `zsh` you can do:

```
rm -- $file
```

While in other shells, you need:

```
rm -- "$file"
```

If you do want globbing, you need to ask for it explicitly as in:

```
rm -- $~file_pattern
```

In your case:

```
for f (*($~EXT)) process-one-file $f
```

(note that by convention, we tend to use uppercase variable names for environment variables)