# Wildcard expansion zsh

Tags: zsh

I'm running on a server where `qstat` gives me the IDs of running jobs (details not important). E.g., say I have three jobs running, `123`, `124`, `125`, then

```
> qstat
123
124
125
```

Each job has a log file in `logs/`. I want to `tail -F` the log files of all jobs.

I attempted

```
tail -F $(qstat | awk -v P=logs '{ print P"/*"$1 }' | paste -sd " ")
```

but I get

```
tail: cannot open logs/*123 for reading: No such file or directory
```

for each job.

---

**I'm running `zsh`, the same thing works in `bash`!**

Apparently, there is no wild card expansion after $(...), could that be? How do I fix this for `zsh`?

Comment: I think this has been asked before... can't find it now though... Anyway, you need `setopt globsubst` to enable filename generation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Glob character within variable expands in bash but not zsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/461360/glob-character-within-variable-expands-in-bash-but-not-zsh). See also [How to use parameter substitution in glob pattern (zsh)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/80574/22142) for another approach...

Comment: @don_crissti, those are about parameter expansion while here it's about command substitution. That's a bit different in that zsh does neither split nor glob upon parameter expansion though it does split upon command substitution, so it's possibly misleading to claim that the issues are duplicate as it could make people think zsh doesn't split upon command substitution.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - fair enough... I'm retracting my vote though this is in the review queue now and it might get closed eventually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, doing filename expansion upon command substitution and other expansions is generally not wanted¹ and not done by default in zsh except in sh/ksh emulation (`globsubst` option).

While you could use `${~$(...)}` to request the use of globsusbt for that particular command substitution (and by the way, you don't need the `paste` part, both space and newline are in the default value of `$IFS`), a much better way to do it with zsh would be:

```
ids=($(qstat))
tail -F logs/*${^ids}
```

Note that if any of those globs fail to match any file, the command will be aborted.

```
tail -F logs/*${^ids}(N)
```

(where `(N)` activates *nullglob* for those globs) would avoid that but would run `tail -F` without argument if there was no file at all (see [Why is nullglob not default?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/204803)).

You could also make it:

```
logs=(logs/*${^$(qstat)}(N))
(($#logs)) && tail -F $logs
```

---

<sup>¹ The fact that `bash` and other Bourne-like shells do it could be seen as a bug. That's one reason why [you need to quote all your variables](/q/171346) there, or why you need `set -o noglob` before using an unquoted `$(...)` when you only want the splitting  part of that split+glob. All more modern shells that don't carry the Bourne shell baggage like `rc`, `es` or `fish` don't do it either.</sup>